# Do we know who the Jedi in the TBB premiere was?

Tags: star-wars, order-66, the-bad-batch

In the first episode of The Bad Batch, we see the aftermath of Order 66 across the galaxy.  When the Bad Batch returns to Kamino, they see a covered dead body whose hand drops a lightsaber.  Clearly, this is a Jedi who was killed in Order 66, but do we know *who* exactly it is?

Obviously, it seems like this is a Jedi who was on Kamino, but why would a Jedi be on Kamino so close to the end of the war?  Is there anyone confirmed in SW to have been on Kamino at the time?  Does the Jedi's lightsaber grant any clues?

Comment: To answer your question about why a Jedi should be on Kamino, presumably to replace [Shaak Ti](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shaak_Ti) in her role as general, observer, protector, and representative of the Jedi Order

Comment: @AntonHinkel Why did Shaak Ti need to be replaced at that point?  She didn't canonically die in Order 66, did she?  I'm not questioning your reasoning for a Jedi being on Kamino, because that does make sense, but I can't remember what happened to Shaak Ti that would mean that she couldn't be on Kamino.

Comment: @SophietheJediKnight wookiepedia says she was killed by Vader at the temple. The cited sources seem to be Disney era, and therefore canon.

Comment: Oh really?  I thought that she was killed by Grievous in a deleted scene that isn't technically canon anymore.  That is interesting; I didn't know she died!

Comment: @SophietheJediKnight the Jedi are on the track of the Chancellor at the end of Episode 3 and therefore I would assume that (almost) all Jedi Masters were called to Corusant to be prepared against the threat of the Sith. She was after all a member of the council.
She was also killed by Starkiller in The Force Unleashed (non canon).

Comment: We can narrow it down to Jedi who own a lightsaber and have at least one hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucasfilm exec Pablo Hidalgo confirmed that the Jedi in question was **an entirely new character** and that she had been invented specifically for the show. It follows that all speculation about her identity (e.g. trying to match her with characters from other parts of the canon) is pointless.

> The Jedi Master was named in the script; **it's a new character**, but I'd
> rather someone more attached the show reveal that information. The
> other droids only have production names of Kaminoan training droid and
> Kaminoan medical droid.
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://web.archive.org/web/20211205230643/https://twitter.com/pabl0hidalgo/status/1467612968506458115)</sup></sub>

As far as I can tell, her name hasn't been revealed yet by any of the cast or crew, although it's possible that her death will form part of a plot-point in a future episode